# pandas - getting unsorted hierarchical columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am having the following dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arrays = [['qux', 'qux', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'],
['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = zip(*arrays)
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)
print df
```

The following is the output:

```
    qux                     baz                     foo                     bar
    one         two         one         two         one         two         one         two
A   0.504208    1.059471    1.488488    0.807279    0.788239    0.110510    0.882414    0.120483
B   0.178940    0.099793    0.460812    -1.388569   1.264663    -0.050531   -0.839683   0.472138
C   0.356101    -0.172082   0.859077    -0.560092   0.450147    1.200750    -0.433077   0.437339
```

When I try to get the `level 0` column I getting the following:

```
df.columns.levels[0]
```

Output:

```
Index([u'bar', u'baz', u'foo', u'qux'], dtype='object', name=u'first')
```

The columns are getting sorted. Is there any way to get the `level 0` column without sorting. The following way:

```
[u'qux', u'baz', u'foo', u'bar']
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) + [`Index.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.unique.html):

```
print (df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique())
Index(['qux', 'baz', 'foo', 'bar'], dtype='object')
```

Alternative solution with [`Index.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print (df.columns.get_level_values(0).drop_duplicates())
Index(['qux', 'baz', 'foo', 'bar'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Awesome. Again @jezrael to the rescue.. It worked like charm. Thanks a lot.